# Unable to reach network from host systems (guest systems are working)

Tags: debian, networking, bridge, xen

After updating my server to the latest version of Xen (4.11.1 on Debian) I don't have a working internet connection on my host system (the guest systems have access). I'm not really sure if the problem is connected to the Xen update or to any other updates I did at the same time :-(

For the internet access I'm using one bridge (`xenbr0`) connected to the `eth0` interface, which is also used by quite some guest systems. The guest systems do have internet access using this bridge. I do have a second bridge (`xenbr1`) which is used for internal communication only, which is not connected to any external interfaces.

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
xenbr0      8000.d6fc6a691328   no      eth0
                                            vif3.0
                                        vif4.0
                                         vif5.0
xenbr1      8000.b226a874c5c4   no      vif1.0
                                         vif2.0
                                         vif4.1
                                         vif6.0
```

Therefore the `eth0` interface has no IP configuration, but the `xenbr0` interface has an IP address.

```
# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 44:8a:5b:29:e6:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

xenbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 148.251.66.43  netmask 255.255.255.224  broadcast 148.251.66.63
        inet6 fe80::d4fc:6aff:fe69:1328  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a01:4f8:202:302a::2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether d6:fc:6a:69:13:28  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

xenbr1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.0.255
        inet6 fe80::b026:a8ff:fe74:c5c4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd1a:1e62:cd84:83f8:172:16:0:1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether b2:26:a8:74:c5:c4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

The default route is configured over the `xenbr0` interface.

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         148.251.66.33   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 xenbr0
148.251.66.32   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 xenbr0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 xenbr1
```

IP forwarding is not configured, since the other machines are using public adresses (no NAT).

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
0
```

Firewall is not configured (`nft list ruleset` has no output, `iptables` is not installed).

Pinging the gateway (`148.251.66.33`) does work on the guest systems but not on the host. As does pinging any external addresses.

Running the following versions:

```
# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 5.2.0-2-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-21)) #1 SMP Debian 5.2.9-2 (2019-08-21)
# dpkg --list "xen-*"
ii  xen-hypervisor-4.11-amd64 4.11.1+92-g6c33308a8d-2+b1 amd64        Xen Hypervisor on AMD64
ii  xen-hypervisor-common     4.11.1+92-g6c33308a8d-2    all          Xen Hypervisor - common files
ii  xen-utils-4.11            4.11.1+92-g6c33308a8d-2+b1 amd64        XEN administrative tools
ii  xen-utils-common          4.11.1+92-g6c33308a8d-2+b1 amd64        Xen administrative tools - common files
# brctl --version
bridge-utils, 1.6
# ip -V
ip utility, iproute2-ss190708
# nft -v
nftables v0.9.2 (Scram)
```

What am I missing? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. Seems to have something to do with an update to `bridge-utils` or maybe the kernel (unfortunately I cannot pinpoint it to a specific version/update).

The behaviour *before* was that the bridge automatically uses the MAC address from the interface, the behaviour *after* the update was that the bridge assigns a randomly generated MAC address (which was blocked on the network side).

After setting the MAC address of the bridge (`ip link set xenbr0 address 44:8a:5b:29:e6:40`) network access works again as expected.